# Arquivo .java não encontrado

Tags: java

Essa é minha primeira vez, fiz uma simples `println`.

Meu código foi exatamente:

```java
class teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("oi");
    }
}
```

Não aparece erro, mas quando eu vou para o terminal e digito `javac teste.java`...!

[image: Terminal]

Comment: E qual é o problema ?

Comment: Uma dica: Não confunda Java com Javascript, são duas linguagens totalmente diferentes. O nome é parecido apenas por causa de burrice de quem deu o nome ao Javascript (que veio depois), pois é algo com pouca ou nenhuma relação com o Java. Originalmente você tinha colocado a tag Javascript na questão ao invés de Java, mas eu já arrumei isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está rodando o comando `javac` a partir da pasta errada. Primeiro navegue até a pasta correta, que é a pasta aonde o seu arquivo `.java` está. E então rode o `javac`.

Para navegar entre pastas no terminal do linux, use o comando `cd`.

Além disso, lembre-se que nomes de classes deveriam começar com letras maiúsculas.

Comment: Ok, consegui, mas surgiu uma nova dúvida: como se acessa pastas no terminal com barra de espaço( exemplo: Arquivos Java) Tive que mudar o nome por conta disso( não que faça muita diferença) agradeço desde já

Comment: @HenriqueBergs Se a pasta tiver espaços, você coloca o nome dela entre aspas. Por exemplo `cd "Minha pasta"`.